# Need for declare destructor as default

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, language-lawyer

According to [these](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#note-73) guidelines:

> If the default destructor is needed, but its generation has been
>   suppressed (e.g., by defining a move constructor), use `=default`.

I can't imagine when code would be ill-formed without explicit default destructor in class which has move constructor.

Can somebody show me example confirms quote above?

```
struct S {
    S() {};
    S( S&& ) {}; // move ctor
};

int main() {
    S s; // there is no need to declare dtor explicitly =default
}
```

Comment: Typo? "If the default **constructor** is needed..."

Comment: @songyuanyao I don't think so. Section describes usage of **destructors**

Comment: Even if section has several typos (with non compilable code mixing `A`/`F` `a`/`act`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it would be some kind of mistake, the implicit declaration of default destructor should have nothing to do with the definition of a move constructor.

From the standard, 12.4$4,5 Destructors [class.dtor]

> 4 If a class has no user-declared destructor, a destructor is
>   implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4). An implicitly-declared
>   destructor is an inline public member of its class.
>
> 5 A defaulted destructor for a class X is defined as deleted if:
>
> (5.1) — X is a union-like class that has a variant member with a
>   non-trivial destructor,
>
> (5.2) — any potentially constructed subobject has class type M (or
>   array thereof) and M has a deleted destructor or a destructor that is
>   inaccessible from the defaulted destructor,
>
> (5.3) — or, for a virtual destructor, lookup of the non-array
>   deallocation function results in an ambiguity or in a function that is
>   deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted destructor.